# replace a char in String

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

Hi I'd like to replace a char in a String.
My problem is that at first you don't know which char it is, so in some cases I get an error message when my char is for example '+'. I don't want my char being interpreted as regex, so what should I do?

May code should be something like this:

```
String test = "something";
char ca = input.chatAt(0);
input = input.replaceAll("" + ca, "");
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: And if you want to replace a literal string by another literal string, then use `String.replace(from, to)`. Reading the javadoc is all you have to do to find these easy solutions.

Comment: My code works perfectly with every char which is NOT '+', '*', '?',... but it should also be possible with these chars.

Comment: Use `String.replace()` instead of `String.replaceAll()`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't expect it to be that easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use regex then.

```
input = input.replace(String.valueOf(ca), "");
```

The `replaceAll` method of `String` takes the `String` representation of a regular expression as an argument.

The `replace` method does not.

See [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 0):

Actually *replace* method is potentially ambiguous, in case when you replace, lets say "zz" -> "xy" in the "zzz" string (result would be "xyz" and not "zxy").

In its turn, *replaceAll* is more flexible and it's behaviour is strictly determined. Needless to say, that it is more expensive, than *replace*.

Definitely, in your case *replace* is the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use replace(Char oldChar, Char newChar) function in String class or use the function below:

```
String replaceChar(String input, char oldChar, char newChar){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();    
    for(int i = 0; i<input.length(); i++){
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        if(c == oldChar)
             sb.append(newChar);
        else
             sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```